# Convert decimal html nonregular ASCII to char ORACLE/PHP

Tags: php, oracle, plsql

I have some data saved in an oracle database as a HTML string such as:

```
<span>This is  &#8216;data&#8217; from 1950&#8211;1980</span></br>
```

And I am trying to save extract it from the database and save it in CSV as

> This is  ‘data’ from 1950–1980

But I don't know how to convert the decimal html nonregular ASCII to it's own char (my data counts many special chars)

I tried `convert` and other functions but nothing really worked. Also, I tried many functions to convert it in PHP but didn't work as well.

Comment: Try [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: `&#8216;` isn't ASCII; It's a Unicode codepoint—just like every other character in HTML and XML. (If you must process it with a character encoding, use UTF-32).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$input="<span>This is &#8216;data&#8217; from 1950&#8211;1980</span></br>";

$output = preg_replace_callback("/(&#[0-9]+;)/", function($m) { return mb_convert_encoding($m[1], "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES"); }, $input);


echo $output;
```

> This is ‘data’ from 1950–1980

credit where credit is due, its in the manual somewhere, but i pulled it out of one of my libraries, so im not sure where :-)

Comment: Thanks for you help. But when I save the data in the CSV it is shown as:
This is â€˜dataâ€™ from 1950â€“1980
I am using  fputs($csv, $line);

Comment: well those are not regular quote marks so depending on the character set between db,script and csv file they are probably getting messed up. you probably need to convert them to regular ''''''''''''' not just decode the entity

Comment: but how can I convert them to regular?

Comment: `str_repalce()` either the `&#8216;` or `‘`

Comment: I have hundreds of special chars in my data

Comment: if the csv file character set cant handle the special chars, you have no other options but to convert them to something it can.

Comment: I just added the bom char in the beginning of the CSV and it worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @SMH When you give a program a CSV file to read, you have to tell it the character encoding (just like for any kind of text file), the delimiter, the text qualifier (and embedded qualifier rule), the line endings, whether it has a header row and the data type for each column. Adding a BOM changed the defaults just enough to work for you.  (Technically, BOM is not a character; it's not part of the text.)